# Unselect radio button in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to unselect the radio button when going to the next frame

```
confirm_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,confirm)
    function confirm( event:MouseEvent):void{
        if(radioGroup1.selection.label== "null")
        {return;}
        else
        {
            answers.push(radioGroup1.selection.label)
           //unselect all selected radio buttons                

        }

    frame= frame+1
    gotoAndPlay(frame); 
}
```

I tried radioGroup1.selected = false and null but didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry , my bad, you cannot set a RadioButton selected property to false, you can only set it to true, meaning that the only way to deselect the button is to select another one, practically setting the other button selected property to true!

```
radioGroup1.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

function changeHandler(event:Event):void 
{
  answers.push(radioGroup1.selection.label);

  //assuming that you have a defaultButton...
  defaultButton.selected = true;

}
```

Comment: You have to create a "hidden" radio button and when you want your radio buttons deselected, you simply select the hidden one.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. And hid the radio btn button.visible=false;